# VBA Deleting buttons with a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to delete all buttons within a range. I've seen plenty of examples on how to delete all buttons within a sheet but not a range. I created a range variable the contains every possible occurance of a button (this is used to reinitialize a form of variable size). The problem is that range doesnt support the object .Shapes or .Buttons.

```
        Set totalTable = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Cells(1000, 1000))
        For Each gen_btn In totalTable.Shapes
           gen_btn.Delete
        Next
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I can't use ActiveSheet becuase there are buttons which i want to keep and becuase the macro is called by a button. Hence the need for a range. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method to see whether the shape is in your range and deletes the shape if it is.

```
Sub Delete_Shapes_In_Range()

Dim btn As Shape
Dim totalTable As Range

Set totalTable = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Cells(1000, 1000))

For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(btn_rng, totalTable) Is Nothing Then btn.Delete
Next btn

End Sub
```

Note that this code will not only delete buttons, but will also delete other shapes. If this is a concern, you can add an `If` statement to skip certain shapes. For example:

```
If Not btn.Name Like "Picture*" Then '<~~Will skip pictures
```

or

```
If Not btn.Name Like "*box*" Then '<~~Will skip textboxes
```

etc. This assumes that you haven't renamed the shapes since creating them.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how to extract the "position" of a button (it's not optimal, but it works). Up to you to adapt it to make it work as it should. This will dislpay the row and column of the top-left cell touched by each button (in the `ActiveSheet`) in successive message boxes.

```
Sub Testing()

    For Each butt In ActiveSheet.Buttons
        MsgBox "Row : " & butt.TopLeftCell.Row & vbCrLf & "Column : " & butt.TopLeftCell.Column
    Next butt

End Sub
```

Comment: so then i would need to determine if that location is within my range and delete if so. that would work. not ideal but I'll play around with it and see what comes of it. thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code:

```
Sub DeleteRangeButtons()
rng = "A1:A10" ' Place range here. 
Dim btn As Button, ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each btn In ws.Buttons
    If isinrange(btn.TopLeftCell.Row, btn.TopLeftCell.Column, rng) Then
        btn.Delete
    End If
    Next btn
Next ws
End Sub
Function isinrange(x, y, rng)
    Cells(x, y).Activate
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(rng)) Is Nothing Then
        isinrange = False
    Else
        isinrange = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @BernardSaucier and Rich, I adapted both of your solutions and got it all working. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on answer by ARich (which was useful to me) since I couldn't add a comment directly. It misses setting btn_rng, but btn.TopLeftCell could be used instead.
Also, I prefer
    btn.Type = msoPicture
instead of
    btn.Name Like "Picture.

Here is my method based on that:

```
Public Sub DeleteIntersectingPictures(ByVal sheetToDeleteIn As Worksheet, ByVal rangeToLookIn As range)

    Dim noOfRowsInSheet As Long
    Dim pictureItem As Shape
    Dim pictureRange As range

    For Each pictureItem In sheetToDeleteIn.Shapes
        If pictureItem.Type = msoPicture Then
            Set pictureRange = sheetToDeleteIn.range( _
                pictureItem.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & pictureItem.BottomRightCell.Address)
            If Not Intersect(pictureRange, rangeToLookIn) Is Nothing Then
                Call pictureItem.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next pictureItem

End Sub
```