# How do I stop duplicate buttons being stacked on top of each other when I paste updates from a master template to working templates?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook I use that has many sheets, each of which uses a template which I duplicate on the sheet to put snapshot information in whenever I need to for the situation specific to that sheet.

As I have worked on improving the template, I have created a master template on which I can do any changes or updates, then created a macro to copy the master, and paste a copy over the existing template on the working sheets, instead of having to manually update the working templates on every sheet individually.

The issue I am finding as that as my template has Form Control buttons in it, every time I push an update, a new button is created directly on top of any buttons already existing, where I was expecting buttons to be overwritten in the same way cells are.

The only thing I could find while searching is how to stop buttons being copied at all, which isn't what I want, I just want to avoid creating a stack of duplicate buttons that will grow endlessly as I update my master template.

My updates macro is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
`Sub PushUpdates()
'
' PushUpdates Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L66").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    .
    .
    .
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False`
```

Comment: Are the first `Activesheet` and `Sheets("Template")` the same? Are these sheets in the workbook containing this code? What exactly do you need to copy? The buttons obviously not. Does the range contain formulas or only values? Please add the clarifications to your post. Something like e.g. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L66").Formula = Sheets("Template").Range("A1:L66").Formula` might do the trick.

Comment: Hi @Black cat. Given that I want to retain other buttons on the sheets I am copying to that fall outside of the range I am copying over, I would like to only delete the shapes in the range I am copying over. I have tried ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("A1:L66") instead of select all but that does not seem to be working.

Comment: Hi @Vbasic2008, Yes and Yes, and Yes. Apologies for the lack of clarity. I need the selection from the "Template" sheet copied over to "Sheet1","Sheet2" etc, including the buttons that are in that selection. Black cat's suggestion could work for me, if there is a  way to select buttons within a range and delete the existing ones before pasting the new ones over.

Comment: You could also delete `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` and create fresh copies of the template and rename them accordingly. Is that something you could work with i.e. is there something else besides the range of values and the buttons in any of the worksheets?

Comment: @VBasic2008 yeah there is additional date on each of the Sheets that i don't want to lose.

Comment: If you can test whether there are already buttons in the range you're pasting to, you can set `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells` to False before you make the next copy (don't forget to set back to True after you're done)

Comment: Thanks Tim and VBasic2008 for your help with this. From Black cat's suggestion I searched up how to delete shapes in a range and found an answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309677/vba-deleting-buttons-with-a-range. With a bit of work I was able to get it going, will add code below.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    RefreshTemplateRange ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L66"), _
                          Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub

'Copy range `rngSource` and paste to range `rngDest`
'If any shapes in the destination range, do not re-copy shapes
Sub RefreshTemplateRange(rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim hasShapes As Boolean
    'any shapes in the destination range?
    hasShapes = RangeHasShapes(rngDest.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, _
                                              rngSource.Columns.Count))
    If hasShapes Then Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False 'skip copying shapes
    rngSource.Copy rngDest
    If hasShapes Then Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True  're-enable
End Sub

'Are there any shapes within the range `rng`?
Function RangeHasShapes(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim shp
    For Each shp In rng.Worksheet.Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(rng, shp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            RangeHasShapes = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next shp
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Generate Template Worksheet Copies

[image]

```vb
Sub PushUpdates()

    ' Define constants.
    Const TEMPLATE_NAME As String = "Template"
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant: SheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    
    ' Reference the workbook and the template sheet.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TEMPLATE_NAME)
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Delete the old sheets and create new copies of the template
    ' renaming each accordingly.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, SheetName As Variant
     
    For Each SheetName In SheetNames
        On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Set ws = Nothing
        End If
        tws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' last sheets? ask if not!
        wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName
    Next SheetName
    
    ' Select the template.
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
    tws.Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Updates pushed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'My new update code

Sub PushUpdates()
' PushUpdates Macro

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L66").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Call DelBtns
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Call DelBtns
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Template - 290423").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


'The code for deleting buttons

Sub DelBtns()
' DelBtns Macro
rng = "A1:L68" ' Place range here.
Dim btn As Shape
    For Each btn In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If isinrange(btn.TopLeftCell.Row, btn.TopLeftCell.Column, rng) Then
    btn.Delete
    End If
    Next btn
End Sub
Function isinrange(x, y, rng)
    Cells(x, y).Activate
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(rng)) Is Nothing Then
        isinrange = False
    Else
        isinrange = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, I can't say I can expand further on the code. I have only been working with excel macros for two weeks, and only for personal things, so I can't break down the items of code with a detailed understanding of how all the parts work. The code for deleting buttons was copied from the other query I linked to in a comment above, and the remainder of the code to copy paste my selected range is literally the recorded macro of me doing it in excel, with the del buttons function called in. Not sure if its the best or most efficient way of doing this, all I know is that it worked for me.